# Multiple VPNs setup from a single station and a router recommendation

Tags: networking, router, vpn

guys.

I need to access geo-restricted applications while traveling. There are two apps - first one can be accessed only from England and the other one only from Ireland. Please advise if implementing the following setup is feasible ?

Im thinking of using a separate VPS in each country and connecting via separate VPNs to them. Would a higher end home router with a VPN capability (for example Asus RT-68U) support this ? Is it possible to connect to one VPN via normal windows account and other VPN via Virtual Box (the second app would be installed in the Virtual Box). Or maybe there are better solutions ? Thanks!

Comment: SU isnt for breaking the law to watch iPlayer and RTE player.